# error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double’ for argument ‘1’ and error: invalid types ‘double[double]’ for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to bring in a partial data file to fill in an array and the user has three attempts to enter the correct data file name. I have repeatedly have gotten these errors. I understand that an array like arr is just a pointer to a block of memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void extract (double arr ,int n, double& i, int& error);

int main () {
    double arr[256];
    int n=256;
    double i=0;
    int error=0;
    extract (arr,n,i,error);
    return 0;
    }

void extract (double arr, int n, double& i,int& error){
    string infile;
    string data="data.txt";cout <<"enter data file name/n";
    cin >> infile;
    while ((error<3) && (data.compare(infile) != 0)){
            error++;
            cout << "error in input. Please try again/n";
            cin >> infile;
            }
    if (error<3){
            ifstream fin;
            fin.open("data.txt");
            while ((i<n) && (fin >> arr[i])){
                    i++;
                    cout << arr[i] << "   ";
                    }
            fin.close();}
    }
```

The errors occur in the while loop that inputs the data from the data file into the array.
Changing the Double i to int i replaced the old problem with

```
error: invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript
```

Here is my data file
84
87
78
16
94
36
87
93
50
22
63
28
91
60
64
27
41
27
73
37
12
69
68
30
83
31
63
24
68
36
30
3
23
59
70
68
94
57
12
43
30
74
22
20
85
38
99
25
16
71
14
27
92
81
57
74
63
71
97
82
6
26
85
28
37
6
47
30
14
58
25
96
83
46
15
68
35
65
44
51
88
9
77
79
89
85
4
52
55
100
33
61
77
69
40
13
27
87
95
40

Comment: `double arr` => `double *arr`

Comment: Plus `double i` => `int i`. An array can't be indexed with floatting values. Only integers.

Comment: I'm not dereferencing it, I'm declaring it. Also if I switch the
    doublei => int i I get 
    error: invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 
`void extract (double arr ,int n, double& i, int& error);` to `void extract (double* arr ,int n, double& i, int& error);` both in the definition and declaration of `extract` function

Edit: The other error is because of `double` type variable being used as an array index, in your case `i` in `extract` function, so either change the type of `i` to `int` or use `i = static_cast<int>(i)` at the very start of extract function, I prefer the first way.

Here is the [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/klj8XId3wEDvOER2) of your code along with the changes done and it compiles and works perfectly.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks that got rid of the "error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double’ for argument ‘1’ " but the other one persists.

Comment: if I switch the double i => int i I get an error: invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript. Sorry about this

Comment: Well, it not connecting to my data file now I guess. it now giving me this
    enter data file name/ndata.txt
0   0   -2.95454e-42   -0.0500865   -2.95454e-42   -1.91024e-41   -2.95454e-42   -1.81681e-41   -1.85814e-41   0   0   0   -0.0500906   -0.0501042   -7.30918e-42   6.36599e-314   -nan   2.122e-314   -8.05283e-42   -7.41431e-42   -0.0500906   -7.41432e-42   -1.91024e-41

Comment: Glad I could help